# What are the pitfalls of using Dill to serialise scikit-learn/statsmodels models?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, statsmodels, dill

I need to serialise scikit-learn/statsmodels models such that all the dependencies (code + data) are packaged in an artefact and this artefact can be used to initialise the model and make predictions. Using the pickle `module` is not an option because this will only take care of the data dependency (the code will not be packaged). So, I have been conducting experiments with [Dill](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill). To make my question more precise, the following is an example where I build a model and persist it.

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
import dill

digits = datasets.load_digits()
training_data_X = digits.data[:-5]
training_data_Y = digits.target[:-5]
test_data_X = digits.data[-5:]
test_data_Y = digits.target[-5:]

class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.normalizer = Normalizer()
        self.clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100.)
    def train(self, training_data_X, training_data_Y):
        normalised_training_data_X = normalizer.fit_transform(training_data_X)
        self.clf.fit(normalised_training_data_X, training_data_Y)
    def predict(self, test_data_X):
        return self.clf.predict(self.normalizer.fit_transform(test_data_X))  

model = Model()
model.train(training_data_X, training_data_Y)
print model.predict(test_data_X)
dill.dump(model, open("my_model.dill", 'w'))
```

Corresponding to this, here is how I initialise the persisted model (in a new session) and make a prediction. Note that this code does not explicitly initialise or have knowledge of the `class Model`.

```
import dill
from sklearn import datasets

digits = datasets.load_digits()
training_data_X = digits.data[:-5]
training_data_Y = digits.target[:-5]
test_data_X = digits.data[-5:]
test_data_Y = digits.target[-5:]

with open("my_model.dill") as model_file:
    model = dill.load(model_file)

print model.predict(test_data_X)
```

Has anyone used Dill isn this way?. The idea is for a data scientist to extend a `ModelWrapper class` for each model they implement and then build the infrastructure around this that persists the models, deploy the models as services and manage the entire lifecycle of the model.

```
class ModelWrapper(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def predict(self, input):
        return
    def dumps(self):
        return dill.dumps(self)
    def loads(self, model_string):
        self.model = dill.loads(model_string)
```

Other than the security implications (arbitrary code execution) and the requirement that modules like `scikit-learn` will have to be installed on the machine thats serving the model, are there and any other pitfalls in this approach? Any comments or words of advice would be most helpful.

I think that [YHat](https://www.yhathq.com/) and [Dato](https://dato.com/) have taken similar approach but rolled out there own implementations of Dill for similar purposes.

Comment: Ok. I have a working prototype of this and it seems to work fine. Now, I need to do the same for R. Any pointers on this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I'm the `dill` author.  `dill` was built to do exactly what you are doing… (to persist numerical fits within class instances for statistics) where these objects can then be distributed to different resources and run in an embarrassingly parallel fashion.  So, the answer is yes -- I have run code like yours, using [`mystic`](https://github.com/uqfoundation/mystic) and/or [`sklearn`](http://scikit-learn.org).

Note that many of the authors of `sklearn` use `cloudpickle` for enabling parallel computing on `sklearn` objects, and not `dill`.  `dill` can pickle more types of objects than `cloudpickle`, however `cloudpickle` is slightly better (at this time of writing) at pickling objects that make references to the global dictionary as part of a closure -- by default, `dill` does this by reference, while `cloudpickle` physically stores the dependencies. However, `dill` has a `"recurse"` mode, that acts like `cloudpickle`, so the difference when using this mode is minor.  (To enable `"recurse"` mode, do `dill.settings['recurse'] = True`, or use `recurse=True` as a flag in `dill.dump`).  Another minor difference is that `cloudpickle` contains special support for things like `scikits.timeseries` and `PIL.Image`, while `dill` does not.

On the plus side, `dill` does not pickle classes by reference, so by pickling a class instance, it serializes the class object itself -- which is a big advantage, as it serializes instances of derived classes of classifiers, models, and etc from `sklearn` in their exact state at the time of pickling… so if you make modifications to the class object, the instance still unpicks correctly.  There are other advantages of `dill` over `cloudpickle`, aside from the broader range of objects (and typically a smaller pickle) -- however, I won't list them here.  You asked for pitfalls, so differences are not pitfalls.

Major pitfalls:

- You should have anything your classes refer to installed on the
  remote machine, just in case `dill` (or `cloudpickle`) pickles it by
  reference.
- You should try to make your classes and class methods as
  self-contained as possible (e.g. don't refer to objects defined in
  the global scope from your classes).
- `sklearn` objects can be big, so saving many of them to a single
  pickle is not always a good idea… you might want to use [`klepto`](https://github.com/uqfoundation/klepto)
  which has a `dict` interface to caching and archiving, and enables you to configure the archive interface to store each key-value pair individually (e.g. one entry per file).

Comment: Hello author, How do I make dill dump result smaller ，Is there any compression levels option？

Comment: @CSQGB: you can chose one of the different serialization protocols... they will produce different sized pickles.  Higher version number tends to be smaller, I believe.  In terms of compression, A library like `klepto` (which uses `dill`) can provide a compressed serialized object.

Answer (score 10):

Ok to begin with, in your sample code `pickle` could work fine, I use pickle all the time to package a model and use it later, unless you want to send the model directly to another server or save the `interpreter state`, because that is what `Dill` is good at and `pickle` can not do. It also depends on your code, what types etc. you use, `pickle` might fail, `Dill` is more stable.

`Dill` is primarly based on `pickle` and so they are very similar, some things you should take into account / look into:

1. Limitations of `Dill`

   `frame`, `generator`, `traceback` standard types can not be packaged.
2. `cloudpickle` might be a good idea for your problem as well, it has better support in pickling objects (than pickle, not per see better than Dill) and you can pickle code easily as well.

Once the target machine has the correct libraries loaded, (be carefull for different `python` versions as well, because they may bug your code), everything should work fine with both `Dill` and `cloudpickle`, as long as you do not use the unsuported standard types.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need to run the model on another server. The idea is to store models in a key-value store and bring them up behind a service endpoint as and when required.

Comment: Then both  `Dill` and `cloudpickle` should work fine for what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I package gaussian process (GP) from `scikit-learn` using `pickle`.

The primary reason is because the GP takes long time to build and loads much faster using `pickle`. So in my code initialization I check whether the data files for model got updated and re-generate the model if necessary, otherwise just de-serialize it from `pickle`!

I would use `pickle`, `dill`, `cloudpickle` in the respective order.

Note that `pickle` includes `protocol` keyword argument and some values can speed up and reduce memory usage significantly!
Finally I wrap pickle code with compression from CPython STL if necessary.