# Issue with FastAPI, Uvicorn, and pickled FunctionTransformer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, fastapi, uvicorn, dill

I have a microservice (`fastapi`) that serves predictions from a model that was pre-trained in a separate repo. Ideally, this microservice only has one job: given an input `X`, a pre-trained `model`, and a pickled `my_transformer`: serve predictions `y`. The microservice shouldn't know/care about what the `model` or `my_transformer` are or how they work.

```
my_transformer = sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer(
    func = lambda y: -np.log(y / 100),
    inverse_func = lambda y_transformed: np.exp(-y_transformed) * 100,
)

y_transformed = my_transformer.transform(y)
model.fit(X,y_transformed)
```

The API should just be able to load the transformer (via `dill` -- because lambda functions aren't pickleable via `pickle` or `joblib`), and call `inverse_transform`. For the most part, this works as expected... that is until I start using `fastapi` and/or `uvicorn`. The error/stack trace I'm getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/[me]/.local/share/virtualenvs/[my_venv]/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 428, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "/Users/[me]/.local/share/virtualenvs/[my_venv]/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/[me]/.local/share/virtualenvs/[my_venv]/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 276, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/[me]/.local/share/virtualenvs/[my_venv]/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 122, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/[me]/.local/share/virtualenvs/[my_venv]/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/Users/[me]/.local/share/virtualenvs/[my_venv]/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/Users/[me]/.local/share/virtualenvs/[my_venv]/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/Users/[me]/.local/share/virtualenvs/[my_venv]/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/Users/[me]/.local/share/virtualenvs/[my_venv]/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/Users/[me]/.local/share/virtualenvs/[my_venv]/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/[me]/.local/share/virtualenvs/[my_venv]/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 718, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/[me]/.local/share/virtualenvs/[my_venv]/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/[me]/.local/share/virtualenvs/[my_venv]/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/Users/[me]/.local/share/virtualenvs/[my_venv]/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 237, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/Users/[me]/.local/share/virtualenvs/[my_venv]/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 165, in run_endpoint_function
    return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
  File "/Users/[me]/.local/share/virtualenvs/[my_venv]/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/concurrency.py", line 41, in run_in_threadpool
    return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args)
  File "/Users/[me]/.local/share/virtualenvs/[my_venv]/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anyio/to_thread.py", line 33, in run_sync
    return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
  File "/Users/[me]/.local/share/virtualenvs/[my_venv]/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 877, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
  File "/Users/[me]/.local/share/virtualenvs/[my_venv]/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 807, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
  File "/Users/[me]/repos/perpetua1/kpi_predictor/basic_app.py", line 23, in root
    my_transformer.transform(arr),
  File "/Users/[me]/.local/share/virtualenvs/[my_venv]/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_set_output.py", line 140, in wrapped
    data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/[me]/.local/share/virtualenvs/[my_venv]/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_function_transformer.py", line 238, in transform
    return self._transform(X, func=self.func, kw_args=self.kw_args)
  File "/Users/[me]/.local/share/virtualenvs/[my_venv]/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_function_transformer.py", line 310, in _transform
    return func(X, **(kw_args if kw_args else {}))
  File "/var/folders/td/_z1v0f3x703gj0wdnfms4h7c0000gp/T/ipykernel_9600/434310704.py", line 4, in <lambda>
NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

I've narrowed it down to potentially be related to how `uvicorn` is run, but don't understand why it breaks. Applying the following fix to my (more complicated) project also doesn't work, so I'm *HOPING* that understanding *why* it's breaking will help inform how to solve the more complicated case.

A basic version of my app looks like:

```
import dill
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel


class ReturnValue(BaseModel):
    value: float


app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/", response_model=list[ReturnValue])
def root():
    with open("my_transformer.dill", "rb") as io:
        my_transformer = dill.load(io)

    arr = np.random.uniform(0, 100, 10)

    return pd.DataFrame(
        my_transformer.transform(arr),
        columns=["value"],
    ).to_dict(orient="records")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # uvicorn.run("basic_app:app", reload=True) # NameError
    uvicorn.run(app) # runs as expected for this simple case, doesn't work for the more complicated app
```

Comment: Try using cloudpickle instead of dill. It is better at managing global references such as np in your case.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32757656/what-are-the-pitfalls-of-using-dill-to-serialise-scikit-learn-statsmodels-models#:~:text=dill%20can%20pickle%20more%20types,cloudpickle%20physically%20stores%20the%20dependencies.

Comment: I'm the `dill` author. I'd disagree... and you'll note that my answer in the above link recommends using `dill.settings['recurse'] = True`, which is essentially uses the same global reference pickling strategy as `cloudpickle` but within `dill` so you can serializes a broader range of objects.  I do agree that it's likely a global reference issue you are experiencing. Best is to try `cloudpickle` and also try changing the `dill` settings, and go with whatever works.

Comment: `cloudpickle` did the trick but I'll keep that in mind. Thanks for the response! I've used `dill` in the past and this was my first time ever having issues so I'm happy to hear it's likely user error.